# Counting unique possibilities when many inputs yield same output.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to get better intuition on solving problems like the following:

Count the number of possible concatenations of $X-Y-Z$, where $X$ is an integer between 1 and 10 (inclusive), $Y$ is an integer between 1 and 50 (inclusive), and $Z$ is an integer between 1 and 100 (inclusive).
Example: $X = 9, Y=15, Z=42$. Then our concatenated number is $n=91542$.

The question is to count how many such unique concatenations are possible. Of course, the crux of the problem is to handle cases where different choices of $X,Y,Z$ yield the same concatenation. E.g., $X=7,Y=23, Z=4$ and $X=7,Y=2,Z=34$ result in the same concatenation.

What would be helpful in addition to a specific solution to this problem is the key tool/way of thinking that is needed to break down such a problem and others like it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all about the absence of leading zeros.

$N$ = 10 times the number of distinct Y - Z concatenations (since a number starting with 10 can only result from X = 10, never from X = 1 )

The only cases in which duplication can occur are those in which a 2 digit Y not ending in zero is followed by a one digit Z, all of these can be reproduced by a one digit Y followed by a 2 digit Z

There are a total of $41-5=36$ possible two digit Y's not ending in zero, any of which can be followed by 9 one digit Z's

$$N = 10( 50\times 100 - 36 \times 9 ) = 46760$$